# XOrg failsafe error: Screen(s) found but none have a usable configuration - NVidia GTX 460

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, 64-bit, xserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force a higher screen resolution from Ubuntu 12.04 and an NVidia GTX460?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236092/how-to-force-a-higher-screen-resolution-from-ubuntu-12-04-and-an-nvidia-gtx460)

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 x64, kernel 3.2.0-24-generic with an NVidia GTX460 and 2560 x 1440 monitor.

Since replacing my ATI video board with the GTX460 I've been unable to get X-windows and Unity running. Initially I booted to a 2D desktop rather than Unity, but since I tried to update my video drivers to NVidia, and purged all the ATI drivers, after the grub menu - small text - Ubuntu boots into a black screen.

The recovery menu is accessible, and from there I can access the root command line, however failsafe Graphics doesn't work.

In recovery mode Failsafe Graphics gets the error message:

> (EE) Screen(s) found but none have a usable configuration
>   Fatal server error:
>   no screens found

By the way when any of the recovery menu selections hang or end in an error, I'm unable to return to the recovery menu or a command prompt - I've tried various commands and key combinations but the only result of say Ctrl+D or exit has been to attempt to boot Ubuntu normally, ending in a black screen. So I end up pulling the plug - I'd appreciate any better ideas for this.

I updated all packages, repaired etc.

I purged and reinstalled xserver: 
`apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg`
`apt-get install xserver-xorg`
`dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

Since reinstalling Xserver the /var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log against PCI where my graphics card should be lists something like (taken from a similar example): 
(--) PCI:*(0:0:16:0) 1002:5046:0000:0000 rev 0, Mem @ 0x94000000/67108864, 0x90000000/16384, I/O @ 0x00000400/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072

`cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep PCI` returns

> (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 460 (GF104) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
>   (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
>   (II) NVIDIA(0): Connected display device(s) on GeForce GTX 460 at PCI:1:0:0

`lspci |grep VGA` returns

> VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 [GeForce GTX 460] (rev a1)

`cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe` returns

> Section "Device"
>           Identifier "Configured Video Device"
>           Driver "vesa"
>   EndSection
>
> Section "Monitor"
>           Identifier "Configured Monitor"
>   EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>           Identifier "Default Screen"
>           Monitor "Configured Monitor"
>           Device "Configured Video Device"
>   EndSection

From the XOrg.failsafe.log it looks like the GTX460 isn't being recognised by the X-server, but lspci shows it is correctly identified.

`lsmod | grep -e nvidia -e nouveau` returns

> nvidia         12319264   0

so an NVidia module is loaded

`jockey-text --no-dbus -l` returns

> xorg:nvidia_current - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (Proprietary, Enabled, In use)
>   which is what I enabled from jockey's gui before the graphics stopped working.

Since I'm running out of options, I installed the latest proprietary NVIDIA drivers 310-19, which I'd previously downloaded `sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-310.19.run`.

That appeared to run smoothly with a couple of questions:

> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed! Continue installation anyway?
>   Answer: Yes
>   Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? 
>   Answer: Yes
>   and whilst failsafe graphics mode still hangs on running fsck, I can boot into a normal Ubuntu 12.04 console from the Grub menu - so this is the best result I've had.

I can't run a graphics session: `sudo start lightdm` gets to

> Starting LightDM Display Manager  [OK]
>   Stopping anac(h)ronistic cron     [OK]
>   then hangs, which Ctrl-Alt-Del is needed to break.

Reviewing /var/log/Xorg.0.log I found the error

> (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
>   (EE) NVIDIA(0):     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
>   (EE) NVIDIA(0):     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
>   (EE) NVIDIA(0):  *** Aborting ***
>   (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failing initialization of X screen 0
>   (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
>
> (EE) Screens found, but none have a usable configuration. 
>        Fatal server error:
>        no screens found

So I reinstalled another version of the NVidia driver. Start networking `/etc/init.d/networking restart` then `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings`

This time `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log` ends

> (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
>   (**) NVIDIA(0):     device DFP-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
>   (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
>   which looks more promising, but attempting to boot Ubuntu leads to a black screen.Running boot in failsafe graphic mode hangs after fsck - which for some reason it insists on running every time.

I've googled round in circles - can anyone suggest how to get Ubuntu to boot into graphics mode?

Thanks!

Update.....

I tried a different monitor with a resolution of 1440x900, also on a DVI-to-DVI cable, and found it worked.

The NVidia XServer Settings application provides a preset list of resolutions up to 1440 x 900 which work with this smaller monitor, but my Achieva Shimian QH270-Lite requires 2560 x 1440, which the GTX460 can do, but XServer isn't recognising it.

The Xorg.0.log contains many instances similar to this:

> [    17.253] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID read for display device DFP-0 is invalid: the
>
> [    17.253] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     checksum for EDID version 1 extension is invalid.

The EDID from the Samsung and the Shimian monitors aren't being read which according to some comments is a problem with NVidia's drivers.

I thought I could fix it by modifying xorg.conf, but I see that file isn't accessed - and again according to comments is deprecated.

xvidtune apparently offers monitor seting configuration but the man page says

> Xvidtune  is  a  client  interface  to  the XFree86 X server video mode extension

which has been superseded in Ubuntu some time ago. Secondly it makes a dynamic adjustment, whereas I want to make a static adjustment.

The NVidia Xserver Settings application won't allow me to enter a larger size for the monitor than the one I'm already using; I've googled and not found a clear answer to how to change the monitor resolution manually.

Can anyone help?

I just reposted my final question in brief form in the hope of some contributions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236092/how-to-force-a-higher-screen-resolution-from-ubuntu-12-04-and-an-nvidia-gtx460).

Comment: Solution in the form of a custom edid for my monitor now found and posted in the briefer query linked above. Thanks to all the contributions I found.

Comment: Since [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236092/how-to-force-a-higher-screen-resolution-from-ubuntu-12-04-and-an-nvidia-gtx460) is in question-answer form and more accessible to others, let's close this as a duplicate of it.